# Function template as parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers

I have been trying to implement in C++11 the function [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) from Python. It seems to work for any kind of callable objet, but I have to specify the template type parameter if I want it to work with function templates. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template<typename T>
T abs(T x)
{
    return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> li = { -1, -2, -3, -4, -5 };
    for (auto i: map(&abs<int>, li))
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I would like it to deduce the `int` parameter from the second argument of the function, and hence be able to write:

```
for (auto i: map(&abs, li))
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

My `map` function is written as:

```
template<typename Callable, typename Container>
auto map(const Callable& function, Container&& iter)
    -> MapObject<Callable, Container>
{
    return { function, std::forward<Container>(iter) };
}
```

where `MapObject` is part of the implmentation and not a real problem here. How could I change its definition so that the template type of the `Callable` object can be deduced from the `Container` object? For example, how can `map` know that we have to use `abs<int>` for a given `abs` when a `list<int>` is given?

Comment: You could use `T = Container::value_type` and add a specialization for `T(T)`...

Comment: @KerrekSB I would like to keep the current compatibility with C arrays.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in this form, because `std::abs` is not even a callable, it is just template. You can do some wired things like `map<std::abs>(li)`, but I don't think it would be better.

Comment: `std::abs` is a template? Defined in a `C` header?

Comment: @DyP Meh, you're right. I actually used a hand-coded one but thought there would be less boilerplate using the standard one. Forgot it was c. Gonna change this.

Comment: @Lol4t0 Hum, could you develop? There are still many things I don't know. If could explain clearly why it is not possible in an answer, I might be satisfied :)

Comment: Uhm... `std::transform(li.begin(),li.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,"\n"), [](int x){ return abs(x); });`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas As a solution to an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), yes. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It works fine, but I would like it to deduce the int parameter from the second argument of the function, and hence be able to write:

```
for (auto i: map(&abs, li))
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that `abs` is not a function, but a function template, and thus there is no *address-of* `abs`, although there is `&abs<int>`, since `abs<int>` (specialization) is indeed a function (generated from a template).

Now the question is what you really want to solve, and in particular you must realize that C++ is a statically typed language where python is a dynamically typed language. It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve here on different levels. For example, the function `map` in python has an equivalent in `std::transform` in C++:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
a = map(lambda x: 2*x, a)

std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
std::transform(v.begin(),v.end(),v.begin(),[](int x){ return 2*x; });
```

Where I have cheated slightly because in python it will create a different container yet in C++ `transform` works at the iterator level and knows of no container, but you can get the same effect similarly:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
std::vector<int> result;
// optionally: result.reserve(v.size());
std::transform(v.begin(),v.end(),
               std::back_inserter(result),
               [](int x) { return 2*x; });
```

I'd advice that you learn the idioms in the language rather than trying to implement idioms from other languages...

BTW, if you are willing to have the user specify the type of the functor that is passed to the `map` function, then you can just pass the name of the template and let the compiler figure out what specialization you need:

```
template <typename Container>
auto map(Container && c, 
         typename Container::value_type (*f)(typename Container::value_type))
     -> MapObject<Callable<T>,Container>;
template <typename T>
T abs(T value);

int main() {
   std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4};
   map(v,abs);
}
```

This is less generic than what you were trying to do, as it only accepts function pointers and of concrete type (this is even less generic than `std::transform`) and it works as when the compiler sees `abs` (without the `&`) it will resolve it to the template, and thus to the set of specializations. It will then use the expected type to select one specialization and pass it in. The compiler will implicitly do `&abs<int>` for you in this case.

Another more generic alternative is not using functions, but functors. With this in mind you can define `abs` as:

```
struct abs {
   template <typename T>
   T operator()(T t) { ...}
};
```

And then pass a copy of the functor in instead of the function pointer. There is no need to determine the overload to be used where you pass the object `abs` into the `map` function, only when it is used. The caller side would look like:

```
for (auto& element : map(container,abs()))
```

Where the extra set of parenthesis is creating an object of type `abs` and passing it in.

Overall, I would try to avoid this. It is a fun thing to do, and you can probably get to a good solution, but it will be *hard* and require quite a bit of c++ expertise. Because it is not supported by the language, you will have to design something that works within the language and that requires compromises on different features or syntax. Knowing the options is a hard problem in itself, understanding the compromises even harder and getting to a *good* solution much harder. And the *good* solution will probably be worse than the equivalent idiomatic C++ code.

If you program in C++, program C++. Trying to code *python* through a C++ compiler will probably give you the pain of C++ and the performance of python.

Comment: +1 I didn't know it was possible to pass a template name and let the compiler deduce the specialization.

Comment: @DyP: That is just imprecise wording on my side :) You are really passing a function, the compiler is just picking one for you. And while most people is not aware of it, it is done very often: `std::cout << std::endl;`

Comment: Great answer, I really do like it! I learnt several things that I did not know before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you really just pass a function? I mean, you're passing the name of a template, so the compiler might have to instantiate it before using it; that is, it's not just overload resolution on a fixed set of functions.

Comment: @DyP: You are just passing a function pointer. The compiler resolves what specialization is the correct one, it *instantiates* it (at the place of call) and passes the function (instantiation) in. The difference between that and passing the template is that the `map` function (or whatever other function you are passing it to) only sees a function, it cannot apply different types to get different instantiations.

Comment: the `typename Functor` isn't required and I'm still having problems compiling this on g++4.8 o.O

Comment: @DyP: Removed the `Functor` template argument. I have not tried any of the snippets above, so they may all fail to compile :)

Comment: I think g++ needs a `remove_reference` on the `Container` for the function pointer type (`::value_type`)

Comment: "A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set. A function template name is considered to name a set of overloaded functions in such contexts." I thought there has to be a special rule, and there it is :) [over.over]

Comment: "I'd advice that you learn the idioms in the language" -- I think that trying to get functional idions to work in C++ is a good goal, since C++ can certainly be used in a functional way - it's just that the support isn't quite there yet (something I hope to redeem). Also, ranges will drive more functional-style too (like Boost.Range already does).

Comment: FWIW, I hope to make `for(auto i : map([]abs, li)){ ... }` possible. :)

Comment: @Xeo: The question there is what does `map()` return. If you are willing to make a copy of the argument, then it is trivially implementable in C++14, and implementable without much complexity in C++11/C++03. *But*, there are different alternatives that are more efficient in C++, for example using an interator adaptor that will apply the lambda to the element on each read (performing the transformation on the fly without the additional cost of the copy of the container), this IIRC is implemented in boost with just C++03 support. That is what I mean with learn the idioms.

Comment: ... that is, because you are used to a `map` function in python with some semantics and you like it, that does not mean that applying exactly the same approach in C++ will produce a good solution.

Comment: Ah, but as far as I'm aware atleast, `map` in Python (3?) creates a *generator*, so it's the same kind of lazy-evaluation, no?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Actually, my current `MapObject` is a generator that just keeps a reference to the container and only performs evaluation (the design being the one of Python 3 `map` and not the Python 2 one). I just find that it is more straight-forward to use than passing iterators around.

Comment: It seems that this has changed :) In python 2.x `map` creates a copy of the original container, rather than a generator.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't deduce it because you never specified that Callable is a template. You make Callable a template template parameter and it should deduce its type for you.

```
template<template <typename T> typename Callable, typename Container>
auto map(const Callable<T>& function, Container&& iter)
    -> MapObject<Callable<T>, Container>
{
    return { function, std::forward<Container>(iter) };
}
```

You might get bitten though as you can't take the address of a template still to be instantiated. Not sure why you need the address-of though...

Comment: If i remember well, we can't do anything with that `T` parameter in real code.